# Is this board trace repairable?

Tags: pcb, repair, trace

The attached picture shows the main board of my Canon S110 camera. The camera was subjected to a shock with the USB cable connected. This resulted in the connector breaking loose from the board with the obvious damage. I use the USB cable to trigger the camera.

My question is, is it repairable? The trace is very thin and can hardly be seen on the magnifier glass of the helping hands. My other question is about the connected pins. Canon have opted for an 11 pin connector on the board side and I'm not sure all 11 are connected to the circuit. Can anyone tell which pins are used?

So to sum things up, is it repairable and what are the minimum tools needed to attempt such a repair. I have a soldering station and good soldering skills but never tried fixing board traces.

Thanks.

[image: board picture]

Comment: That would be hard or impossible for a professional - as good as impossible for someone without experience. That is, unless you're happy with a bodge job, e.g. having wires connecting the origins of the traces (i.e. other components on the board) leading out to a replacement socket. I suspect this is along the lines of how a repair shop might attempt it anyway. The problem would be if other traces are damaged.

Comment: My sole use for the USB port is to trigger the camera. So i'm only using 2 pins. Would be more than happy to have that functionality restored even if it meant having 2 wires coming out. I have tested the camera before taking it apart and all seemed ok.

Comment: If you can figure out which two pins you used, then it sounds like an easier job.  As Spehro says below you'll have to scrap the solder mask to expose the traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat possible. I would try to source a connector that's similar and epoxy it into place, expose the copper traces by carefully scraping off the solder mask with an X-acto knife or scalpel, then use very fine (eg. AWG 38 or AWG 40) magnet wires to jumper the pins to the traces (the jumpers should be kept short). It still may not work after all this. If your eyes are not very good, a decent stereo microscope would help a lot.

You might want to take it to a cell phone repair guy and see what they want to give it a try.